# Get JSON list embeded another object with Retrofit

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I have an server rest, that provides JSON. I can get an user, but not a user list using Retrofit.

User JSON example (server/users/2):

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "name",
  "lastName": "name"
}
```

User list example (server/users):

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "name",
        "lastName": "name"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Ime",
        "lastName": "Léonide"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I guess that is caused by "_embedded". I don't think I can change this.

Java code:

```
@GET("users/")
Call<List<User>> usersList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
@GET("users/")
Call<UserResponse> usersList();

class UserResponse {
    @SerializedName("_embedded")
    UserList embedded;
}

class UserList {
    @SerializedName("users")
    List<User> userList;
}
```